# tunnel http over https

Tags: http, tunnel, https

I am sitting in an japanese appartment and this weird appartment company needs a username and password to enter the internet (It's a .htaccess like dialog). I cant get this username and password but indeed all https:// connections are working.

Is there a way to access the internet over https only and also tunnel all http connections through https?

Answer (score 0):

This was in fact already answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/301485/http-to-https-tunnel).

The program [Stunnel](http://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/using-stunnel-to-encrypt-unsecure-connections.html) adds SSL to all TCP connections, namely http; giving you https access in any situation.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question in this case, because a tunnel requires support on both ends, what is needed is a proxy outside the network.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you need a proxy that supports https outside your network. I've crafted a google query to find such proxies:

https://www.google.com/search?q=free+proxy+supporting+https