# ssh trough HTTPS without a proxy

Tags: ssh, https

Is it possible to ssh trough HTTPS without a proxy? using normal tools, something like ThinVNC does
The network is closed from the outside world, only access to websites is allowed, and that's only trough a proxy that blocks the usage of other proxies.

Comment: What are normal tools? And why do you need HTTPS if you have an encrypted SSH session anyway? For tunneling SSH through HTTP you can use `httptunnel` but it doesn't support HTTPS.

Comment: i cannot use httptunnel as the network is closed and outside it's only accessible trough a proxy, that blocks the usage of other proxies - ony ThinVNC works

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, I've done it by myself by changing the listen port of my ssh server in /etc/ssh/sshd_conf from 22 to 443 (HTTPS). Be sure that your server is not already listening on this port before.

Don't forget to restart the sshd service after your modification.

Also, use the -p option when you're using the ssh client to set the port.

Comment: Works only if just the port is checked. It won't work with deep packet inspection.

Comment: You could also try to install GateOne on a web server:

http://liftoffsoftware.com/Products/GateOne

It's free to use (open source) and it's using HTML5 to emulate a SSH terminal. If you don't want everyone to see it, restrict the access of you page with a password prompt and a robot.txt.

Comment: i think what i need is something like httptunnel but for https

Comment: See this post:http://superuser.com/questions/301485/http-to-https-tunnel The guy recommends to use stunnel, maybe this is what you want

Comment: stunnel will not work because all the traffic has to go trough the proxy, and CONNECT is blocked

Comment: Well, I'm out of solutions. I still recommend to use GateOne since it's a really good way to ssh with HTML5. Good luck!